# Can I insulate my refrigerator to improve efficiency?

Tags: energy-efficiency, electricity, cooling, insulation, food-storage

Any "reasonable" methods would be appreciated. I have heard that this can be done but I'm dubious that it would do much. Maybe if I put polyethylene on the right bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the greatest efficiency improvement can be obtained by cleaning the condenser coils on the bottom and/back . In a home unit the coils,especially on the bottom collect a lot of lint , pet hair , etc. Vacuum them annually or more often. I have also added aluminum window screen to protect the coils from lint. If you use foam ,I think you will find polyurethane and polystyrene easier to obtain.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any guidelines on where to apply insulation, other than avoid places where heat is coming out?